# Eliminar un elemento especifico de una lista en haskell

Tags: lista, haskell

Tengo que hacer una función que reciba un numero y una lista y se elimine de la lista el elemento señalado por el numero siendo este la posición del elemento que sera borrado.

Ejemplo 3 ["casa","perro","comida","celular"]
          = ["casa","perro","celular]"

Esto es lo que llevo  hasta el momento.

quitaElemPos :: Int -> [a] -> [a]

quitaElemPos 1 (x:xs) = []

quitaElempos n (x:xs) x == n quitaElempos xs n 
               | otherwise = x:( quitarElemento xs n )

Comment: Hola @oscar, ¿ Que has intentado para realizar esa función ?

Comment: Hola, esto lo que e avanzado.                                                                quitaElemPos :: Int -> [a] -> [a]

quitaElemPos 1 (x:xs) = []

quitaElempos n (x:xs) x == n quitaElempos xs n 
               | otherwise = x:( quitarElemento xs n )

Comment: Hola, @oscarescobedo. Te aconsejaría que _mimaras_ un poco más las preguntas. Si ése es el código que has intentado, no lo habrás podido compilar de ninguna de las maneras. Aparte de errores de formato, no puedes comparar `x == n` sin especificar `Eq a`, además de que no tiene sentido si buscas posiciones.

Answer (score 0):

La idea es montar una función recursiva que vaya simplificando el problema en cada iteración.

Podemos hacerlo así:

```hs
quitaElemPos :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
quitaElemPos _ [] = []
quitaElemPos 1 (x:xs) = xs
quitaElemPos n (x:xs) = x : quitaElemPos (n-1) xs
```

Estos son los criterios aplicados:

- Si la lista está vacía, no hay ningún elemento qué quitar
- Si tenemos que quitar el primer elemento, devolvemos el resto (`tail`)
- Para el resto de casos, aplicamos la función a la cola de la lista, restando uno a la posición a borrar.

Esta versión funciona, pero tiene una pega: si pasamos una posición negativa o mayor que la longitud de la lista, recorre innecesariamiente toda la lista sin alterar nada. Podemos evitar que lo haga:

```hs
quitaElemPos :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
quitaElemPos _ [] = []
quitaElemPos 1 (x:xs) = xs
quitaElemPos n (x:xs) | 0 < n && n <= length (x:xs) = x : quitaElemPos (n-1) xs
                      | otherwise = x:xs
```